# Swagger doesn't detect request parameters correctly

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger-2.0

Given a controller like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = GET)
@ApiOperation(value = "Find items")
public List<Item> find(Query query) {
  ...
}

class Query {
  String text;
  int limit;
}
```

Spring MVC lets me do requests like `/items/?text=foo&limit=10`. Unfortunately, Swagger (or SpringFox?) thinks this endpoint takes a single "query" (JSON object) parameter. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the key is to both have getters/setters (setters alone are not sufficient) and use `@ModelAttribute` (which otherwise isn't necessary in Spring MVC).